Storing CUPS printer config in home directory
Is there a way to configure CUPS to store printers.conf in a user's home directory instead of the global /etc/cups/printers.conf? Basically, I'm wanting to allow per-user configuration of local printers.
Extra Details
I'm using Qubes OS. By default, everything except /home is wiped when a VM is restarted, and the system boots based on the template VM being used. This means that when I set up printers, they are lost every time I restart my VMs unless I set up the printers inside my template VM - this isn't ideal.
